# mysql fail to start bash_completion errors

Tags: linux, debian, mysql

So after upgrading my debian system, mysql does not start anymore with command "service mysql start". I get:

```
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. linksys:/home/users/stan# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Mon 2014-07-28 10:03:56 PDT, end at Mon 2014-07-28 12:07:07 PDT.
-- Jul 28 12:07:07 linksys mysql[5509]: -su: 89: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found 
   Jul 28 12:07:07 linksys mysql[5509]: -su: 92: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found 
   Jul 28 12:07:07 linksys mysql[5509]: -su: 101: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expec 
   Jul 28 12:07:07 linksys su[5536]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user mysql
   Jul 28 12:07:07 linksys systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
   Jul 28 12:07:07 linksys systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
```

Looking at `/etc/init.d/mysql` it looks like the command to start mysql is: `su - mysql -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe > /dev/null 2>&1 &"` but I get more bash_completion errors:

```
-su: 29: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: [[: not found
-su: 35: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: [[: not found
-su: 51: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: shopt: not found
-su: 57: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 62: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 65: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 68: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 71: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 74: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 77: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 80: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 83: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 86: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 89: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 92: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: complete: not found
-su: 101: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

No logs in /var/log/mysql/. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
-su: 29: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: [[: not found
```

tells me that /bin/sh isn't a bash shell (on modern Debian, it's almost certainly dash), but it's trying to source a bash script.  So, the question you need to answer is why a non-bash shell is trying to source the bash_completion script.  I'm guessing that the problem is one of the dotfiles in the `mysql` user's home directory.

Try running:

```
grep bash_completion ~mysql/.*
```

to find out which one.  My educated guess would be that the mysql user has a `.profile` in his home directory that tries to run bash commands without checking that the shell he's in is bash.

Alternately, the simplest fix to get things up and running again might be switching /bin/sh to be bash instead of dash.  According to https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh you can do that by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and following some on-screen prompts to set /bin/sh back to bash.

Comment: I thought I was running bash. echo $0 shows bash. What I ended up doing(based on suggestion from a different forum) was what you are leading to which is I am not running bash. So 'dpkg-reconfigure dash' to bash. It worked right away. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user3212716 You had /bin/bash on your system, and your login shell was set to /bin/bash, but /bin/sh wasn't a symlink to /bin/bash, it was a symlink to dash instead.